# Alterar valores vindos da BD numa tabela

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-datatables, tabela-html

Estou com problemas quanto aos dados que vou buscar à base de dados, isto quando os altero na minha tabela.

**HTML**

```
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="vendaTabela" width="100%">
      <thead>
       <tr>
         <th data-class="expand">Cód.</th>
         <th data-hide="phone">Designação</th>
         <th data-hide="phone">Qnt.</th>
         <th data-hide="phone,tablet">Uni.</th>
         <th>Preço</th>
         <th>Desconto</th>
         <th>IVA</th>
         <th>Sub-Total</th>
        </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
        <tr id="tr0">
         <td class="codigo" contenteditable="true" onblur="codArtigo ( )"></td>
         <td id="ac" class="designacao autoC" contenteditable="true" onblur="nomeArtigo()"></td>
         <td class="quantidade" contenteditable="true" onblur="subtotal ( )"></td>
         <td class="unidade" contenteditable="false"></td>
         <td class="preco" contenteditable="true"></td>
         <td class="desconto" contenteditable="true"></td>
         <td class="iva" contenteditable="false"></td>
         <td class="total" contenteditable="false"></td>

        </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
```

**JQUERY**

```
//PREENCHER TABELA COM OS DADOS DO ARTIGO A PARTIR DO SEU CÓDIGO
codArtigo = function () {
    var $linhas = $("#vendaTabela tbody > tr");
    var val = $('#entidade').val();
    var xyz = $('#list option').filter(function () {
        return this.value == val;
    }).data('xyz');
    var idEntidade = xyz ? '' + xyz : 'No Match';

    $linhas.each(function () {
        var designacao = $(".designacao", this);
        var codigo = $(".codigo", this);
        var unidade = $(".unidade", this);
        var iva = $(".iva", this);
        var qtd = $(".quantidade", this);
        var preco = $(".preco", this);
        var precoArt = $(".preco", this);
        var desconto = $(".desconto", this);
        var subTotal = $(".total", this);

        myJSRoutes.controllers.ArtigoController.getArtigobyEntidadeId(idEntidade, codigo.html()).ajax({
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.length > 0) {

                    myJSRoutes.controllers.ArtigoController.getArtigobyId(codigo.html()).ajax({
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data.length > 0) {
                                $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                                    designacao.html(value.nome);
                                    unidade.html(value.unidade.simbolo);
                                    iva.html(value.iva.valor + " %");
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    })


                    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                        preco.html(value.preco.toFixed(2) + " €");
                    });
                } else {
                    myJSRoutes.controllers.ArtigoController.getArtigobyId(codigo.html()).ajax({
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data.length > 0) {
                                $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                                    designacao.html(value.nome);
                                    unidade.html(value.unidade.simbolo);
                                    iva.html(value.iva.valor + " %");
                                    precoArt.html(value.preco.toFixed(2) + " €");
                                });
                            } else {
                                alert("Artigo Desconhecido");
                                codigo.text("");
                                designacao.text("");
                                qtd.text("");
                                preco.text("");
                                precoArt.text("");
                                unidade.text("");
                                iva.text("");
                                subTotal.text("");
                                desconto.text("");
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        })
    })
}
```

O que se passa é o seguinte:

-Vou buscar um artigo à BD (código:1, preço: 12);
-Depois de o inserir na primeira linha e alterar o seu preço que veio da BD (12), para 15 por exemplo, quando insiro outra linha e insiro novamente o mesmo artigo, o que vem da BD é (preço:12, e bem), mas altera-me o valor da primeira linha de 15 para 12.

Porquê que me altera o resto das linhas do mesmo artigo para o valor original da BD se eu estou a referênciar a linha? `var preco = $(".preco",this)` ?

PS: coloquei uma questão idêntica e era problema na declaração das variáveis, como a questão já estava extensa decidi colocar outra.

Comment: Melhore a formatação do código porque tá difícil de entender e poste o HTML também, por favor

Comment: De facto estava mal formatado mas assim com a formatação coloca aquele scroll horizontal.

Comment: Acredito que seja por isso: `var $linhas = $("#vendaTabela tbody > tr");`, está pegando todas as linhas da tabela e percorrendo #.each logo abaixo; Não te dou a certeza disso, não tenho como testar; Caso queira ... você pode alterar seus eventos para: http://api.jquery.com/on/; `$(document).on('blur', 'table#vendaTabela > .codigo', function(e) {$linha = $(this).closest('tr'); //RESTO });`

Comment: Caso queira um exemplo só pedir @HugoMachado;

Comment: Obrigado vou testar e já vejo :)

Comment: Eu dessa forma vou buscar a linha, mas se quiser alterar uma coluna dessa linha como faço ?

Comment: Está perfeitamente funcional, pelo menos ainda não deu problemas. Obrigado @RafaelWithoeft ;)

Comment: @HugoMachado Estava almoçando, conseguiu resolver seu problema da forma proposta?

Comment: Sim sim, muito obrigado @RafaelWithoeft ;)